# Seeming discrepancy between renv::status() and renv::restore()

Tags: r, renv

I'm experimenting with using [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/) in a project to support reproducibility. I created a lockfile without a problem, and now after cloning on a new machine here is the output from two `renv` commands:

```
> renv::restore()
* The library is already synchronized with the lockfile.

> renv::status()
The following packages are used in this project, but not installed:

    shinydashboard, shinyalert, magick, shinytest2, ggplot2,
    shinybusy, shiny, DT, rdrop2, gmailr, shinydashboardPlus,
    plotly, shinyWidgets, cowplot

Consider installing these packages -- for example, with `renv::install()`.
Use `renv::status()` afterwards to re-assess the project state.
```

My question: **this seems inconsistent; is it?** That is, `restore` ("Restore a project's dependencies from a lockfile") seems to be saying "nothing to do, all needed packages are present" while `status` ("Report differences between the project's lockfile and the current state of the project's library") reports missing packages. Is my understanding of these output messages wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your lockfile and see if the packages mentioned to be installed are recorded in the lockfile. My guess is that the lockfile doesn't have these packages yet "snapshot", hence the renv::status highlights that packages need to be installed.
It could be, before cloning on the new machine, the renv::snapshot wasn't run and the lockfile wasn't updated on the remote location.